# Looking for a package allowing user-entered profiles

Tags: looking-for-a-script

Title was a little hard to work, but take this as an example.

User goes to site, creates account, and then has his/her own profile to edit. Let's say the profile includes height, weight, sex, eye color, etc..

I've really only used wordpress before, but I'm sure something else would cater to this better. The entire site is focused around a person having their own profile page with the info they supply.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've built quite a number of communities using BuddyPress, which not only allows extra custom fields during WordPress registration, but also gives your site a very high degree of social media functionality -- everything from walls and Twitter-style @user messaging to forums, wikis and image galleries. Plus there are a lot of themes and plugins for it, and an excellent support community.

http://buddypress.org

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with wordpress, I have implemented sites with profiles using regi-plus-redux plugin.  It allows you to make as many custom fields to your sign up page as you want as well as customize your pages, that with the CYC (customize your community) plugin which helps skinning some pages that are under the admin section (profile) and you are well on your way without much additional customizations.